# Enable use CAPL browser in CANoe

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

I can't find CAPL browser under Tools

[image: Screen shot of Tools. Note CAPL Browser is not present]

Even I can't add and remove Node

[image: Screen shot of context menu with no option to add and remove Node]

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Which variant of CANoe are you using? This looks like _CANoe pex_ or _CANoe run_, which can only be used for executing existing configurations, not for development.

Comment: Looks like you are using CANoe without license.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using demo version of CANoe,
First you need a Pro licensed VN hardware to use CAPL.
Second while you open any configuration, there will be a pop up window opens at starting, there you can change option to "Pro" option instead of "Run"